# Is there any way to remove overrides for standard buttons by APEX code?

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, button-overrides

I'm developing the managed package, which contains some extended lwc form for new account creation.

Reassign "new" button on account object is manual operation (after managed package instalation):
[image]
During testing in scratch org, I have found, that after the uninstalling my package, I cant reassign "new" button behavior, and see an error:
[image: acc buttons edit]
I want to use apex UninstallScript class, to check "new account button" behavior.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to check behavior of standard new account button by apex code?
2. Is there a way to delete override of standard new account button by apex code?
3. Is there a way to stop uninstall the managed package process with an error message?
4. Is there some another way to solve my problem? May be some best practises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configurations could be changed using Metadata API, not native apex, so 1 and 2 answer is no.

You can use metadata API to deploy those [action override](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm) for Account

```
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>new</actionName>
        <type>default</type>
     </actionOverrides>
</CustomObject>
```